# Number of generators of localized ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain and let $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ be a prime. Assume that $\mathfrak{p}=(a,b)$ and suppose that $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ is principal.

> Is it true that $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ must be generated by either $a/1$ or $b/1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

For each non-zero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of a Dedekind domain $A$,  $A_\mathfrak p$ is a (discrete) valuation domain.

Comment: Yes, therefore I have that $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a PID, but now how I can go on? Can expand your answer please?

Comment: In a valuation domain (whether discrete or not), ideals are linearly ordered.

Comment: I think Bernard meant : for $c \in A_\mathfrak{p}$, $|c|_\mathfrak{p} = q^{-n}$ if $c \in \mathfrak{p}^nA_\mathfrak{p}, c \not \in \mathfrak{p}^{n+1}A_\mathfrak{p}$. If $\mathfrak{p} = (a,b)$ then $|a| = q^{-1} $ or $b = q^{-1}$ and hence $\mathfrak{p} A_\mathfrak{p} = \{ c \in A_\mathfrak{p}, |c|_\mathfrak{p} < 1\} = a A_\mathfrak{p}$ or $b A_\mathfrak{p}$. @VincenzoZaccaro

Comment: I think it's simpler...$\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}=(a,b)$, but, as Bernard says, $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a DVR, therefore I can assume $(a)\subseteq (b)$, then $a$ can be killed in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Yes that's what I proved I think

Comment: That's. I only use the property that either $aA_\mathfrak p\subset bA_\mathfrak p$ or $bA_\mathfrak p\subset aA_\mathfrak p$.

Comment: @reuns: Yes, that's what you proved, but with many technicalities. The real argument works fro *any* valuation domain, not only discrete ones.